# PHP fread ignoring length parameter

Tags: php, fread

So I'm trying to upload videos to twitter using the API and I am using fread to split the video into chunks.
The response I get is hundreds of null objects, now the null, I think, should be the correct response but the amount is certainly not. There shoould only be 11 (for a 10.8mb video).
Here is my code, please can someone help. I've wasted days and days trying to get this to work :(

```
$fp = fopen($media_path, 'rb'); 
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $chunk = fread($fp, 1048576);
    $tmhOAuthUpload = new tmhOAuth();
    $tmhOAuthUpload->request(
        'POST',
        $tmhOAuthUpload->url('/1.1/media/upload.json'),
        array(
            "command" => "APPEND",
            "media_id" => $media_id,
            'media_data' => base64_encode($chunk),
            "segment_index" => $segment_id
        )
    );
    $segment_id++;
    $results = json_decode($tmhOAuthUpload->response['response']);
    var_dump($results);
}
```

Comment: _I've wasted days and days trying to get this to work_ So are there any useful bit of information you produced in order to debug this.

Comment: `$segment_id++;` seems to be getting incremented, but has it been initialised?

Comment: Yes, $segment_id = 0 at the start. I get this error (about 1000 times) "SegmentIndex must be between 0 and 999" after 999 NULL objects.

Comment: So how many files are you uploading in one go?

Comment: Just the 1. It's a 10.8mb video but trying to split it into 1mb chunks as per the Twitter API docs

Comment: I would add a check that the $chunk is actually valid immediately after the read. Check that it isn't false and the length of it. Throw an exception if it isn't was it expected. The upload... put it in a 'try {} catch... throw error. and display the error message. It shouldn't take long to debug with this extra information.

Comment: Testing suggestion: `while (!feof($fp)) {  $chunk = fread($fp, 1048576);  $segment_id++;  echo $segment_id . ', '; }` How many segment_ids do you see printed

Comment: I will try the 'try and catch' now.

Comment: I'm getting over 2000 segement_id's returned.

Comment: The chunks are valid but they are only 8192 bytes (the first chunk is 16004 bytes).

Comment: If you read the notes in the manual  about 'fread' it explains how to combine them together. Thanks for posting this information. Basically, you need a another nested loop to combine these chunks into the size you require before processing them and uploading them. Note: the 'length' parameter is a 'maximum length'. It may return less as shown here.

Comment: Absolute LEGEND! Thanks very much @RyanVincent for your help. It's finally working and I haven't pulled all of my hair out yet! :) I can't thank you enough!

Comment: Thanks also @RiggsFolly your help is very much appreciated too :)